# Put generated Image object into Flame.Images asset cache

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

What is the most effective way to put a generated image into the  `Flame.Images` asset cache?

I can get the image from this method, but I don't know how to put the resulting `Image` object into the cache.

```
Future<Image> decodeImageFromPixels(
    Uint8List pixels,
    int width,
    int height, {
    bool runAsWeb = kIsWeb,
  })
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what it is that you want to do? Do you want to put your decoded image into the image cache so that you can fetch it with a name?

Comment: Yes, I want to generate an image from assets when uploading and save it in the cache

Answer (score 0):

That does currently not work since the image cache only works on files.
But you can quite easily create an image cache (just a map) in your game class, either as a static map or one that you can access through components that have the `HasGameRef<YourGameClass` mixin.

It would look like this:

```dart
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  final generatedImages = <String, Image>{};

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    final image = await Flame.images.decodeImageFromPixels(...);
    generatedImages['image name'] = image;
  }
}
```

Then in your component class where you want to use the image, if it is a `SpriteComponent` for example:

```dart
class MyComponent extends Component with HasGameRef<MyGame> {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    sprite = Sprite(gameRef.generatedImages['image name']);
  }
}
```

or if you are not extending a component, but still using a `SpriteComponent` you can do this wherever you want that component (that has access to the `gameRef`):

```dart
final spriteComponent = SpriteComponent.fromImage(gameRef.generatedImages['image name']);
```

Note you could also make the `generatedImages` map static and just access it with `MyGame.generatedImages['image name'];` without having a `gameRef`.